# Django: ModelViewSet router not working for update action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using ModelViewSet and Modelserializer for a blog like project.

It could be my difficulty in understanding the implementation; I can't get the **update** action to work via **calling it through router**, only the *list action is working* with the route I have defined.

When I put the url : `127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/1`, to return the blog with ID 1 **to edit**, it returns `{"Detail": "Not Found."}`.

This is my view:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

I have also overridden the save and update methods in the serializer class, don't know whether it was needed for ModelViewSet in ModelSerializer.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        article = Article.objects.create(
            article_title = self.validated_data['article_title'],
            article_content = self.validated_data['article_content'],
            ...
        )
        return article

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.article_title = validated_data.get('article_title', instance.article_title)
        instance.article_content = validated_data.get('article_content', instance.article_content)
        ...
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ...
```

And the `urls.py` file:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blogs', ArticleViewSet, basename='articles-list')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

My question is:
1. How do I specify urls for the ModelViewSet actions (in my case the `update` action)?
2. Will defining only one url suffice all my needs with **every** ModelViewSet actions? if so how?

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to DRF.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your questions:

1) Upon registering `ModelViewSet` in api router, it will create all required urls for the following actions. In your case it would be following:

- list (GET request to `/api/blogs/`)
- retrieve (GET request to
  `/api/blogs/{pk}/`)
- create (POST request to `/api/blogs/`)
- update (PUT request to `/api/blogs/{pk}/`) (it will validate all fields of the model)
- partial update (PATCH request to `/api/blogs/{pk}/`) (it will run no validation - you can send only
  fields you've decided to change)
- delete (DELETE request to `/api/blogs/{pk}/`)

So, basically router does most of the job for you about registering viewset actions.

2) I don't completely get it, but if my guess is correct - answer is the same as to first question.

About what you are doing wrong - I am not sure, but did you try appending slash at the end of your request (i.e not `/api/blogs/1` but `/api/blogs/1/`)

Comment: For the UPDATE action, I'm trying the same url `/api/blogs/{pk}/`, but it's returning this error: `"details": "Not found"`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was trying the url `localhost/api/blogs/1`. It was returning this: `"Detail": "Not Found"`. 
It was because there were no instance saved with the id 1. All my saved intance had different ids which i didn't notice before. After putting available ids, it returned desired result.

Comment: Where is the instance.save placed?

Comment: In the serializers.py file, in the `update()` method, if defined.